# What does the `platforms` argument to `setup()` in `setup.py` do?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-wheel

Looking through several projects recently, I noticed some of them use `platforms` argument to `setup()` in `setup.py`, though with only one value of `any`, i.e.

```
#setup.py file in project's package folder 
...   
setup(
      ...,
      platforms=['any'],
      ...
)
```

OR

```
#setup.py file in project's package folder
...  
setup(
      ...,
      platforms='any',
      ...
)
```

From the name "platforms", I can make a guess about what this argument means, and it seems that the list variant is the right usage.

So I googled, looked through [setuptools docs](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html), but I failed to find any explanation to what are the possible values to `platforms` and what it does/affects in package exactly.

Please, explain or provide a link to explanation of what it does exactly and what values it accepts?

P.S. Also tried to provide different values to it in my OS independent package and see what changes, when creating wheels, but it seems it does nothing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`platforms` is an argument the `setuptools` package inherits from `distutils`; see the [*Additional meta-data* section](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data) in the `distutils` documentation:

> *Meta-Data*: `platforms`
>   *Description*: a list of platforms
>   *Value*: list of strings

So, yes, using a list is the correct syntax.

The field just provides metadata; what platforms does the package target. Use this to communicate to tools or people about where you expect the package to be used.

There is no further specification for the contents of this list, it is unstructured and free-form. If you want to use something more structured, use the [available Trove classifier strings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers) in the `classifiers` field, where tags under `Operating System`, `Environment` and others let you more strictly define a platform.

Wheels do not use this field other than to include it in the metadata, just like other fields like `author` or `license`.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that, but except that it's a list of strings there's no more information on it on that link. Will pip consider this field when you try to install some package, say on linux, and `platforms` is set to `win32` or something?

Comment: @Nikita: there is little more to say about it. There are no automated tools using this field.

Comment: So basically it's outdated and has no real use? I mean, you can get intended platforms from `classifiers` if you have too.

Comment: @Nikita: exactly; `classifiers` is far more structured and defined.

Comment: I see, thank you! But let's see if anyone will have something to add.

Comment: Sure, feel free. If it helps anything, I've been building and releasing Python projects for 15+ years now, I'm pretty confident there is no other answer. :-)

Comment: I found an actual "use" of the `platforms` attribute.  When I build my own extension with `bdist_wheel` and install it with `pip install`, I see the platforms listed in the _<pkg>.dist-info/METADATA_ file.  I'm not saying this is a significant use or affects anything else, just that it's not ignored, and is forwarded to the installation as metadata.  Not specifying it in _setup.py_ causes that file to say the platform is "Unknown".

Comment: @Jim: yes, which is what my answer already states. The metadata is copied across, but no _installer_ uses the data automatically to make any installation decisions.

Answer (score 8):

Just an update to provide more information for anyone interested.

I found an accurate description of `platforms` in a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#platform-multiple-use).

So, "*There's a PEP for that!*":

[PEP-0345](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/) lists all possible arguments to `setup()` in `setup.py`, but it's a little old.

[PEP-0426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/) and [PEP-0459](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0459/) are newer versions describing metadata for Python packages.

Comment: Status of pep426 and pep 459 is withdrawn.

Comment: This answer should be updated as irrelevant (All 3 PEPs listed are were withdrawn)